# Reversing the order of summation in $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Here is a summation that is supposed to be solved:

$$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} i$$

The author says it can be solved by substituting with $i = n-j$:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i = \sum_{n-j=1}^{n} (n - j)$$

The next step of the simplification he doesn't explain, nor does he explain any simplification past that:

\begin{align*}
& = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (n-j)\\
& = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} n - \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}j\\
& = n \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}1 - \sum_{j=1}^{n}j + n
\end{align*}

<sub>This isn't the solution yet I have left that out because it's irrelevant.</sub>

How was he able to change $\sum_{n-j=1}^{n} (n - j)$ to $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (n-j)$? Is that a rule of summation that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All he's doing is reversing the order of summation. Try writing it out. Originally, $i$ ranges from $1$ to $n$, so our summation is:
$$
S_n = 1 + 2 + \cdots + i + \cdots + n
$$
After making the substitution $i = n - j \iff j = n - i$, we note that $j$ now ranges backwards from $n-1$ to $n-n$, so our summation is:
$$
S_n = [n-(n-1)] + [n-(n-2)] + \cdots + [n-(n-j)] + \cdots + [n - (n-n)]
$$
By simplifying the terms in the round brackets and reversing the order of summation, we obtain:
$$
S_n = [n - 0] + [n-1] + \cdots + [n-j] + \cdots + [n - (n - 1)]
$$
so that now $j$ is ranging from $0$ to $n - 1$.

Comment: Why does he want to reverse it?

Comment: Presumably, because he's going to do a cool Gaussian pairing trick. Notice that $S_n + S_n$ is:
$$
(1 + n) + (2 + (n - 1)) + \cdots + ((n - 1) + 2) + (n + 1)
= \underbrace{(n + 1) + (n + 1) + \cdots + (n + 1) + (n + 1)}_{n \text{ times}} = n(n + 1)
$$
so it turns out that:
$$
S_n = \frac{n(n + 1)}{2}
$$

Comment: How can I learn to understand this stuff better, like you? I've been reading this stuff for about a week and I'm constantly getting stuck on simple things that I can't think my way out of.

Comment: Well that's a bit harder to answer hahah. I guess it just takes a lot of practice and experience. What you're doing is great; you're questioning the steps that the author is making in a proof instead of blindly accepting what they did. Keep up the hard work, and I'm sure that things will start to make more sense.

Comment: Thanks! Can you also help me understand something else? This is very small and simple: On [this](http://www.math.uaa.alaska.edu/~afmaf/classes/math231/assign/sum_ex.pdf) page where the author writes $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} 2k-1=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} 2k-1+2(n+1)-1$, where is the $\text{...} +2(n+1)-1$ coming from. That's where I got confused.

Comment: The upper limit of summation changed from $n+1$ to $n$. The author "popped off" the last term in the summation at $k = n+1$.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thanks. Do I always have to do that to prove by induction? Is it a sure fire way to always prove summations?

Comment: Yep! Summations are inherently recursively defined, so they're certainly great for practicing induction proofs. If you have any other questions, feel free to ask them in a separate question and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 5):

If $i=n-j$, then $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{i=n} i = \sum_{n-j=1}^{n-j=n} (n-j) = \sum_{j=n-1}^{j=0} (n-j) = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(n-j)$.

Comment: Why does $i=n$ on top of the first summation?

Comment: The summation is from $i=1$ to $i=n$. If you make a substitution only in the first value ($i=1$) but not the last value ($i=n$), then you will not be summing the correct terms. So $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(n-j)$ in your third display is not correct.